# Periodicity of a trigonometric function

Tags: trigonometry, periodic-functions

How to find the fundamental period of the function $|\sin x - \cos x|$ and $|\sin x - \cos x|$ + $|\sin x + \cos x|$?

Please tell the proper method to find the period of the functions like these.
I have just started studying functions so i am not so good at it so please go easy with the explanation.

Comment: What do you mean by symmetrical? Do you mean f(x)=f(-x)?

Comment: No @NeerajBhauryal not necessarily $f(x) = f(-x)$ or $f(x) = -f(-x)$ its just that function is symmetrical about $x =a$ or $y = a$ (or symmetrical about any line/point)

Comment: $\sin x$ is symmetrical. Do its periods get halved, too?

Comment: Still here, Neelesh?

Comment: Umm.. sorry for late reply was busy with school studies. No the period of $\sin x $ does not gets halved it's $2\pi $ and is always $2\pi$

Comment: OK, then it's not true that if a function is symmetrical then its period gets halved. Right? By the way, if you want to be sure I'll see a comment directed to me, you have to put @Gerry in it.

Comment: Busy some more?

Comment: Ya final examination closing in. I simply want to ask why and how the period of the function $|\cos x + \sin x |$ is $\pi$ with a understandable and easy method @GerryMyerson

Comment: It's at most $\pi$ because $|\cos(x+\pi)+\sin(x+\pi)|=|\cos x+\sin x|$ for all $x$. It's at least $\pi$ because the function evaluates to zero at $3\pi/4$ and at $7\pi/4$ and nowhere in between.

Comment: But how can we predict the fundamental period of a function like that (if we do not want to put is some values)?

Comment: You can't get something for nothing. You have to put in some work, somewhere. Also, if you want to be sure I see a comment, you have to include @Gerry in it.